# Is it possible to change the center of a taylor series by substitution?

Tags: calculus

If we have the taylor series of some function $f(y)$ centered at $y=0$ and we substitute $y=x-a$ then will this give me the taylor series of the function centered at $a$ ?

Comment: I think your purpose is to derive Taylor series for $f$ about $a$ given its Taylor series about $0$. That's possible via substitution $y=y-a+a=x+a$ where $x=y-a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because you get 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(0)\,(x-a)^k}{k!}
$$
and not
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(a)\,(x-a)^k}{k!}
$$

Consider for instance the series for the sine at $0$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.
$$
If you shift to $\pi/2$ you get 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(x-\pi/2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.
$$
On the other hand, the Taylor series for the sine at $\pi/2$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(x-\pi/2)^{2k}}{(2k)!}.
$$
If you evaluate the first series at $\pi/2$ you get $0$, since $\sin(x-\pi/2)$ are $\pi/2$ is zero. If you evaluate the second series at $\pi/2$, you get $1$, which is $\sin \pi/2$.

A more extreme example is $e^{-1/x^2}$ at $0$. Its Taylor series is $0$ for all terms. So if you shift it, you still get $0$. On the other hand, at any point other than zero the function is analytic and its Taylor series will be something else, but certainly not zero.

Comment: I see, but would what I'm talking about work for the geometric series? Shifting it? I can't think of a reason why it wouldnt

Comment: I expanded my answer. I have no idea what you mean by "geometric series": a Taylor series is a power series representing a function; a geometric series is a series.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but in my book they calculate the taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ at $z=-i$ by $\frac{1}{1-i+z+i} = \frac{1}{1-i}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{z+i}{1-i}}$ and then using the geometric series on the rightmost term.  Is it valid to do things like this, since they didn't use the taylor series formula?

Comment: Yes. If you happen to write an analytic function as a power series around a point, within the radius of convergence  that's  unique : so it doesn't  matter how you find the series (i.e., either by the formula or by a trick).

Answer (score 2):

No, but I think it is worth noting that you will get the Taylor series of the funcion $g(x)=f(x-a)$, centered at $a$.
$$g^{(n)}(x)=f^{(n)}(x-a)$$ so
$$g^{(n)}(a)=f^{(n)}(0)$$
this is a powerful method for finding some Taylor series (and power series representations) when the function has some shifting property. 
For example $e^{a+b}=e^a \cdot e^b$ leads to the Taylor series of $e^x$ centered at $a=1$ via the substitution $u=x-1$.
$$e^x=e^{u+1}=e \cdot e^u= e \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e \cdot u^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e \cdot (x-1)^n}{n!}$$
Something like $\sin(x)$ centered at $\theta$ could be done in a similar fashion. Via $u= x - \theta$.
$$\sin(x) =\sin(u+\theta)=\sin(u) \cos(\theta)+\cos(u) \sin(\theta) \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(\theta) \frac{(-1)^nu^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin(\theta) \frac{(-1)^nu^{2n}}{(2n)!} $$
so
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(\theta) \frac{(-1)^n(x-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin(\theta) \frac{(-1)^n(x-a)^{2n}}{(2n)!} $$